# python replace nan to zero for specific rows

Tags: python, pandas, fillna

Hi i have a dataframe like this below, just want to replace nan to zero from third row to sixth row.
is there any easy method for this issue?

```
att1 att2 att3 
1 1 5.0
1 1 Nan
1 1 4.0
1 2 1.0
2 1 Nan
2 2 3.0
2 2 4.0
```

to

```
att1 att2 att3 
1 1 5.0
1 1 Nan
1 1 4.0
1 2 1.0
2 1 0
2 2 3.0
2 2 4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe DataFrame.fillna() will do this for you.

Link to Docs for a [dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) and for a [Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html).

Example:

```
In [7]: df
Out[7]: 
          0         1
0       NaN       NaN
1 -0.494375  0.570994
2       NaN       NaN

In [8]: df.fillna(0)
Out[8]: 
          0         1
0  0.000000  0.000000
1 -0.494375  0.570994
2  0.000000  0.000000
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is only for whole data. what i want is to replace part of it. Thanks

Comment: Can you show me the part of dataframe where you want this to apply ? 

or you can do df[att3 ].fillna(0)

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish your goal, you can use the pandas `.fillna()` method and apply it across the target rows using the `.iloc()` accessor: `df.iloc[3:7, :] = df.iloc[3:7, :].fillna(0)` Note, the iloc accessor stop value (i.e. 7, in this case) is non-inclusive. Documentation links: [pandas fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html), [pandas iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html?highlight=iloc#pandas.DataFrame.iloc)

Comment: If you find that this solves your problem, please remember to upvote and accept the answer.